# C# Web broswer control remove white space

Tags: c#, html, css, winforms, webbrowser-control

I got a problem with white space surrounding the video, I've added margin: 0 which fixed the top white space. But now I still got white space on other positions. I also tried to resize the browser control to match the iframe. But when I resize, the same thing happends: [image]

```
var embed = "<html><head>" +
  "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\"/>" +
  "</head><body style=\"margin: 0\">" +
  "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"{0}\"" +
  "frameborder=\"1\" allow =\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" ></iframe>" +
  "</body></html>";

var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JvSZKB2WNKg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0";
webBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format(embed, url);
```

Comment: could you share with us what your question is ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it in the description. But it's about white space around the video. How to remove it.

Comment: Looks like your web browser control is bigger than the iframe in the page you're loading within it.  Default web page background is white, hence the border.

Comment: you can edit your question and still describe it there. Any info about your question should not be in comments but in your question. Also show us what you have tried so far

Comment: But when i change the size of the browser control, the video face same destiny.

Comment: you could set the background-color of your web page to black

Comment: @GuidoG okay i edited the first post

Comment: I know, but i want rather to fix the issue than dancing around it :/

Comment: I played around with the iframe width and height. I got as close as possible before scrollbars appears. Still bit white-space at the bottom.

Comment: Isn't the `WebBrowser` control based on an ancient version of IE anyway? I'm surprised it can still handle YouTube...

Comment: What should i use instead then xD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- Set the size of the `WebBrowser` control same as the `iframe`
- Turn off scrolling of `body` tag by setting `scroll="no"`.
- Turn off padding and margin for `body` tag, by setting `style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"`.
- Remove borders of `iframe` tag by setting `style="border:0px;"` for body.

So your code should be:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    int w = 560;
    int h = 315;
    this.webBrowser1.Width = w;
    this.webBrowser1.Height = h;
    var embed = "<html><head>" +
    "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\"/>" +
    "</head><body scroll=\"no\" style=\"padding:0px;margin:0px;\">" +
    "<iframe style=\"border: 0px;\" width=\"{1}\" height=\"{2}\" src=\"{0}\"" +
    "allow =\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" ></iframe>" +
    "</body></html>";
    var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JvSZKB2WNKg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0";
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format(embed, url, w, h);
}
```

Comment: I cant belive that it works. You are the best, but does frameborder work for you? Seems not working for me

Comment: What's `frameborder`?

Comment: As you see on the picture, it's like a frame around the video. A grey frame.

Comment: For me, there is no such border. Here is [what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cECT.jpg).

Comment: Yes same here, i mean i want a border around the video. Since else it looks blended with the background.

Comment: There are multiple solutions for that. For example, use `w+2` and `h+2` for browser width and height; then for iframe, set style `style=\"border: 1px solid #fff;\"`. You don't need to use `frameborder` attribute.

Comment: `#fff` is white color. Use a different color. You can play with those values to get expected result. You have all you need in hand :)

Comment: Works perfectly, i dont know what i would do without your help. Thank you very much. Only thing i got left is to stop either the video or browser when user switch control user.

Comment: I can share a solution for that. Let me know if you asked any question about it. Also it's not clear what you mean by "switch user control". I can share a solution for example when you click on a button on the form, stop the video. Then you can change it based on your requirements.

Comment: That would be great: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053211/c-sharp-pause-video-or-stop-web-browser-when-switching-usercontrols