# C# Pause video or stop Web browser when switching UserControls

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube, webbrowser-control

I have a problem, when i'm playing a video on e.g movies control and then switch to home control with bringToFront() method. The video is still playing, atleast the sound is still doing it.

```
public partial class MoviesControl : UserControl
{
    public MoviesControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int width = 560;
        int height = 315;
        webBrowser1.Width = width + 2;
        webBrowser1.Height = height + 2;
        var embed = "<html><head>" +
        "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\"/>" +
        "</head><body scroll=\"no\" style=\"padding:0px;margin:0px;\">" +
        "<iframe style=\"border: 1px solid #0000ff;\" width=\"{1}\" height=\"{2}\" src=\"{0}\"" +
        "frameborder=\"0\" allow =\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" ></iframe>" +
        "</body></html>";
        string url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JvSZKB2WNKg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0";
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format(embed, url, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your desired behaviour? And please share your code

Comment: Well there is not much to share, expect the movie control. When user switch control by clicking on example home control. The button execute homeControl.bringToFront(). Then it should either pause the video which is playing on the web browser on the movie control or just stop it.

Comment: If you share some code, we can at least *try* to help you, but without code, that's hardly possible in most cases. About the rest of your comment: That information that should be present in the question itself, not in a comment. I'd suggest to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49053211/edit) your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) allows you to control the player using javascript code.
To be able to use that script API, you should load the `iframe` by adding `enablejsapi=1` to query string.

Then for pausing a video, you are looking for `pauseVideo` command. Using the following script you can pause the video:

```
var i = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
i.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}}', '*');
```

To be able to call it from windows forms, put it in a function in your html code, then call it using [`WebBrowserDocument.InvokeScript()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1a88bz(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the broswer control.

**Example**

```
int w = 560;
int h = 315;
this.webBrowser1.Width = w + 2;
this.webBrowser1.Height = h + 2;
var embed = "<html><head>" +
"<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\"/>" +
"<script>"+
"function stop() {{"+
"var i = document.getElementsByTagName(\"iframe\")[0].contentWindow;" +
"i.postMessage('{{\"event\":\"command\",\"func\":\"pauseVideo\",\"args\":\"\"}}', '*');" +
"}}</script>"+
"</head><body scroll=\"no\" style=\"padding:0px;margin:0px;\">" +
"<iframe style=\"border: 1px solid #fff;\" width=\"{1}\" height=\"{2}\" src=\"{0}\"" +
"allow =\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" ></iframe>" +
"</body></html>";
var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JvSZKB2WNKg?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&amp;showinfo=0";
webBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format(embed, url, w, h);
```

Then you can pause the video simply whenever you want:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("stop", null);
```

Comment: Looks great, but how can i invoke when i switch control. Since i have not access to the movie control outside of it.

Comment: You should create a `public void Stop(){webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("stop", null);}` method in your `MoviesControl`. Then from outside of your control, you can call it simply `moviesControl1.Stop();`

Comment: It did not work, still hearing the sound of the video playing :/

Comment: My fault, did not see there was another line on the video link. Works perfectly. You are truely the best! Is it possible to force quality to 480p?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation. It seems [`setPlaybackQuality`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackQuality) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Cheers mate :)!